# table-footer-group and table-header-group not taking the width of the table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

Firstly I am doing a responsive website, the layout is a bit complicated.I have two columns in a table. The client need last column first in mobile and the first column last.

I did that using table-header-group and table-footer-group. The parent table takes the width of the Container, but the columns not taking table's width.

Please find the attached image here.[image]

You can see the table width in the last of the image, but the column's not taking that width.

Can anyone know how to fix the column's width according to the table.

Please find the HTML below

```
<div class="col1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="colA">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/redis-2/467/Redis_Logo-256.png" />
        </td>
        <td class="colB">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here the
[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mshafeequemsn/Bg9QP/)

Comment: responsive web design is not to be made with tables! use divs instead

Answer (score 1):

Add display:table and width:100% to the parent tr to make columns full width.

```
<div class="col1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr style="display:table;width:100%;">
        <td class="colA">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/redis-2/467/Redis_Logo-256.png" />
        </td>
        <td class="colB">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-media-icons/32/Paypal.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8kdh2u0/)

Comment: I know this had been down-voted, but exactly what I was looking for. Not actually using a table, but setting the display:table to the parent element solved my 100% issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a table. Instead float "column 2" to the right and (depending on how you define the widths of the columns) either float "column 1" left, or give it a right margin the same as the width of "column 2". For mobile just remove the floats and margins.

If this doesn't help, post the **relevant** HTML and CSS, best as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net#).

Comment: As per the requirement I am not able to nothing in the HTML tags, I can only edit the css, Anyway i will add fiddle for this.

Comment: I have edited the questions with the HTML and also provided the link to the fiddle

Comment: I assume the problem ist that by setting the `td`s to `table-header/footer-group`, you have them inside a `tr` which doesn't make sense and confuses the browser. I would consider this not solvable with the current requirements.