# can table-header-group or table-footer-group maintain a self supportive true 100% width?

Tags: html-email

A similar issue has been addressed here, [table-footer-group and table-header-group not taking the width of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356899/table-footer-group-and-table-header-group-not-taking-the-width-of-the-table). However, I wanted to revisit the concept.

In this example, as the media query is triggered, I am using CSS display properties to rearrange the table elements. More specifically, table-header-group will stack the right column above the left column. However, once stacked in this scenario, the two columns/containers do not retain 100% width, related to the parent tag.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { 

*[class].block  { display:block !important; } 
*[class].up    { display:table-header-group !important; }
*[class].down  { display:table-footer-group !important; }
*[class].m320 { width:100% !important; min-width:320px !important; }
*[class].w100p { width:100% !important; }
*[class].w80p { width:80% !important; }
*[class].w20p { width:20% !important; }
}
```

```html
<table width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" border="0" class="w100p">
 <tr>
  <td width="320" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#00ff33" class="w80p down"><img style="display:block;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/60/50" /></td>
  <td width="320" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" class="w20p up"><img style="display:block;" src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to understand the display properties of table-header-group and table-footer-group, as I am not using them in the conventional sense. This is intended to be included in HTML email, which restricts the pre-media query layout to using a table based layout.

Question: Is it possible for elements with a display style of table-header-group or table-footer-group maintain a self supportive true 100% width?

Thank you World